# How do you set Cell Properties so that sequential images overwrite each other in a single output cell?

Tags: graphics, front-end

This produces 10 output cells, but I would like it to be in just one cell so I can do a video screen capture.  I'm working with 30,000 800x800 RGB images, and it completely overruns Animate and Manipulate and my RAM, so I am thinking about starting from scratch by writing code for a very simple viewer that imports each image, displays it, imports a second image, displays it, deletes the first image, etc.

```
g = Table[RandomImage[1, {250, 250},
    ColorSpace -> "RGB"], 10];
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, Print[g[[i]]]; 
Pause[1]]
```

Comment: If you have Mathematica 12.2 then you may want to consider [VideoGenerator](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VideoGenerator.html) as an alternative.

Comment: To answer you question directly: Look up `Dynamic`. You can create a cell by evaluating `Dynamic[image]`. This cell will always show whatever `image` is, so you can run code separately that updates `image` to get the effect you're after.

Comment: One more comment: If you have a bunch of images that you want to turn into a video, this can easily be done using the ffmpeg command line utility. It's easy to find a copy and paste command that will do it on websites like Stack Overflow.

Comment: Dynamic works great.